# Errorproof prepared statements with PHP

Tags: php, error-handling, exception, prepared-statement

I am trying to understand how error handling in prepared statements in procedural PHP style should work.

According to the documentation, `mysqli_prepare` and `mysqli_stmt_execute` output the boolean value `FALSE` on failure. Great, so if I run the following code I should be able to know when something doesn't work:

```
if ($my_query= mysqli_prepare($my_conn, "SELECT * FROM my_table")){

    if (mysqli_stmt_execute($my_query)){
        // DO WHATEVER I NEED TO DO
    } else {
        // HANDLE ERROR
    }

} else {
    // HANDLE ERROR
}
```

The problem is that `mysqli_prepare` and `mysqli_stmt_execute` do NOT always output `False` on failure, they raise an exception. For instance, if my SQL syntax was not right (see following example) I would get a `mysqli_sql_exception`.

```
if ($my_query= mysqli_prepare($my_conn, "SELECTTTT * FROM my_table")){

    if (mysqli_stmt_execute($my_query)){
        // DO WHATEVER I NEED TO DO
    } else {
        // HANDLE ERROR
    }

} else {
    // HANDLE ERROR
}
```

This calls for a try-catch statement, but then...are the `if` even necessary?

My question here is: What's considered a failure in the execution? (no exception rised but those methods return a False value) Is it really necessary to use `if` statements if I use a `try-catch` block? Because I feel that a `try-catch` block would be enough, but the PHP documentation examples (for instance, the [mysqli_stmt_fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) examples) only use `if`s clauses for dealing with errors.

I would like to hear how you handle failure on this cases. In addition, if you know of any good tutorial regarding this matter, I would appreciate it if you could send me the link. Most tutorials I've seen do not care about error handling.

ANSWER:

If you run the code I provided you might not be able to reproduce my error. The problem was that, after connecting to the database, I had the following line of code:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

This turned my warnings into errors, that would throw an exception. Without it, the `if` statements DO make sense. The answer is in the comments of this post.

Comment: Wrap the whole mysqli business in the `try{}` then write the `catch{}` block to deliver the exception.  You can still check for "success", count rows, and check logic as normal inside the `try{}` block.

Comment: @mickmackusa Mmmm, that link didn't really solved my question, I know how to use a `try-catch`. I'm a bit confused by how both methods `mysqli_prepare` and `mysqli_stmt_execute` work. What's the point of checking for "success" with an `if` statement if, whenever there is an error, I need to catch the exception? What's considered a failure in the execution? (no exception rised but those methods return a `False` value)

Comment: Ideally you should only have to deal with exceptions, not check each return value for falsiness on top. See also [Turning query errors to Exceptions in MySQLi](//stackoverflow.com/q/14578243)

Comment: @mario Your link gave me the answer. I had the following line of code `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`, which turned warnings into errors. Thanks!